# (!Test.isRunningTest())-How do we write test class to cover this?

Tags: unit-test

I have written a test class for my apex class. I am able to cover all portion except this

[image]

how do i cover this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any chance you did a search first?

> Generated code is saved as an Apex class containing the methods you
>   can invoke for calling the Web service. To deploy or package this Apex
>   class and other accompanying code, 75% of the code must have test
>   coverage, including the methods in the generated class. By default,
>   test methods don’t support Web service callouts and tests that perform
>   Web service callouts are skipped. To prevent tests from being skipped
>   and to increase code coverage, Apex provides the built-in
>   WebServiceMock interface and the Test.setMock method that you can use
>   to receive fake responses in a test method.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing.htm

You will need to implement the above and remove the `test.isRunningTest()` as it was the old way of doing things where there was no way to test it...

Comment: Thank you... :) that was useful... so i need to change my apex code as i will not be able to cover this ?

Comment: @Azeem - Yes, you have to update your code as well as create the mock implementations, then update your tests.